# How can I replace a column value with a name in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running this query:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(type) FROM "table"  where id = 8 GROUP BY type;
```

With this result:

```
6   3814
8   341
5   328
```

I'd like to have something like this, where I can specify names:

```
Arbitrary Name  3814
Other name       341
Test Name        328
```

Instead of the type column listing 6, how can I get it to have a custom name like `Test Column 6`, or `Fun Column 5`? I'm using postgres.

Comment: usually people create separate table with such names and join with it in query to display human readable names for IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT 
>    CASE WHEN type = X THEN 'SOME TEXT' ELSE 'OTHER TEXT' END ,
>   COUNT(type) FROM "table"  where id = 8 GROUP BY type;

Answer (score 1):

**1st )** If you have alot of "type" in your record then you should create a new table to store it information ( typeid , name , detail ) then you can get it like :

Example

```
SELECT typegroup.typename,Count(typeid) from 'table',typegroup where 'table'.id=8 and typegroup.typeid='table'.typeid GROUP BY 'table'.type
```

**2nd )** If you don't have alot of "type" in your record then you can try these statement

```
SELECT 
   IF (type = '6','8','5',REPLACE(type, 'Arbitrary Name','Other name','Test Name')) AS type 
   FROM table 
   WHERE id = 8
GROUP BY type
```